# Drop in traffic in Google Analytics after change in domain caused by setup?

Tags: .htaccess, google-analytics, analytics

Any google analytics wizards out there? i'm troubleshooting a drop in traffic for a company website. I'm wondering if a simple miss in google analytics settings during a URL change was to blame.

Here's the outline:

1) Company's website is abc[dot]com 
2) Company changes domain to xyz[dot]com but keeps the same website source code and google analytics code 
3) abc[dot]com does not redirect to xyz[dot]com but it serves the same site code and google analytics code 
4) Company does not update the URL of the website in the Google Analytics dashboard (see screenshot here ----> https://www.evernote.com/shard/s20/sh/afa0ce35-6898-4f9c-9f24-4009e41a52bd/594581c27cb10f2e8f27cc55bd59cf23/deep/0/Google%20Analytics.png)

Can anyone tell me if not updating the site URL would affect what was tracked?

Comment: No, that does not actually matter. Check for a drop in organic search traffic, serving duplicate content on two domains might have affected your SEO ranking.

Answer (score 0):

The account Profile doesn't matter but what does your GA code look like?

Are you passing the `_setDomainName` tag in GA?

If you are and it is set for the original domain `abc.com` then when a customer lands on `xyz.com` ga will not fire.